# Playing mp4 video via Gstreamer with hardaware acceleration on RPI4

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, mp4, raspberry-pi4

Is there an example of pipeline for Gstreamer(gst-launch) to play mp4 video with HW acceleration on Raspberry pi4?

Comment: So you could not find any information on that? Please try first and ask here if you are stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find any solution. Only one thing I found is example of pipeline which do not use HW acceleration.

Comment: Check for `omxh264dec`.

Comment: I  tried: 
`<pre>gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! autovideosink`
And get this error: 
`Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause. 
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0: Could not initialize supporting library. Additional debug info: gstvideodecoder.c(2535): gst_video_decoder_change_state (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0: Failed to open decoder 
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline`